# Take 1 worksheet from an workbook and save it as a new excel document

Tags: vba, excel, save

I have a workbook, saved as xyz.xlsm.  This workbook has 3 worksheets (sheet1, sheet2, sheet3).  I want to create a macro in VBA that will copy sheet3 and save it in a new excel document in path G:\Michael\work\uploadfiles.  I want the macro to name this new document the current date + text content in cell D3 from sheet2, ie. (01/02/15 Mike Jones).

Comment: Use the macro recorder to record your actions while doing this, then try modifying the code. Post back if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but something like this should work.

Define your current book as a variable:

```
Set thisBook = ActiveWorkbook
```

Then you need to create the new Excel file:

```
Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
```

Then copy sheet3 from `thisBook` to `newBook`:

```
thisBook.Sheets("sheet3").Copy After:=newBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

To save the new one, do something like:

```
dim filePath, thisDate as string
' VBA probably won't like the slashes in the date, so replace them.
thisDate = Replace(Date(),"\"," - ")
filePath = "G:\Michael\work\uploadfiles\" & thisDate & "Mike Jones.xlsx"
newBook.SaveAs FileName:= filePath
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code does the job.

By default, save1sheet saves the sheet you indicate from the workbook containing the macro, but you can chose the active workbook (if that is different) or any open workbook.

```
Public Sub save1sheet(sheetNameOrNumber, toFile As String, Optional fromBook = "")
    Dim theBook As Workbook, theSheet As Worksheet
    If fromBook = "" Then
        Set theBook = ThisWorkbook
    ElseIf fromBook = "_active_" Then
        Set theBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Else
        Set theBook = Workbooks(fromBook)
    End If

    Set theSheet = theBook.Sheets(sheetNameOrNumber)
    theSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True, toFile
End Sub

Sub saveTheSheets()
    Dim pathTemplate As String, path As String
    pathTemplate = "C:\Temp\{date} {person}.xlsx"
    ' G:\Michael\work\uploadfiles

    path = Replace(pathTemplate, "{date}", Replace(Date, "/", " - "))
    path = Replace(path, "{person}", "Mike Jones")
    save1sheet "sheet3", path

    path = Replace(pathTemplate, "{date}", Replace(Date, "/", " - "))
    path = Replace(path, "{person}", "Dirk Horsten")
    save1sheet 2, path, fromBook:="_active_"

    path = Replace(pathTemplate, "{date}", Replace(Date, "/", " - "))
    path = Replace(path, "{person}", "Hamilton Blake")
    save1sheet "Sheet1", path, fromBook:="ThatOtherBook.xlsx"
End Sub
```